# USB appears to prevent Windows from sleeping

Tags: windows-8, usb, sleep

After running the diagnostic tests mentioned in many answers concerning why Windows might not sleep I discovered that USB devices were the culprit (well, that and Windows Media Player, but that was easy enough to solve)

[image: usb suspension]

While the (very small, it seems) error message above lists 3 usb problems, it appears to be solved simply by removing the usb headphones from the machine (which would be a pain to do regularly).

Should I be altering anything in relation to power options?
[image: suspension]

As it stands my machine will turn off the screen, but will stubbornly refuse to sleep.

Comment: The 3 USB problems all say "**Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping**" ...

Comment: @DavidPostill as these are the only errors returning from the diagnostics, I'd be inclined to ignore that disclaimer; not least the fact that plugging out the headphones (after dealing with the media player issue) allowed my computer to go to sleep automatically for the first time in months.

Comment: You could try with USB selective suspend setting **disabled**. That's what I have set here and have no USB devices preventing sleep - including USB combined headphones/mic (used for skype).

Comment: @DavidPostill I might give that a shot - although Microsoft literature claims that having selective suspend disabled will prevent the machine from going asleep (your counterexample may be a useful exception)